# How to search and display items through php,html and from database (cpanel)

Tags: php, html, database

I want to create a form which allows the user to type in a search and have it pick up the values from a database and display them, for some reason I can't get my query to work it just displays "could not search" even after i type in the search criteria. The include("global.php") is what i use to connect to the database. For my other codes to connect to the database, i uses these:

```
include("global.php");

session_start();
$userid = ($_SESSION['userid']);
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) == false)
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}   

$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, position FROM profiles WHERE userid=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userid); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $position);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Below is the issue i am facing. Above is an example of how i normally connect to the database and retrieve datas i want. But i do not knw how to apply it to codes below.

```
<form action ="search.php" method = "post">

      <input name="search" type="text" size="30" />

      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

</form>

<?php
include("global.php");
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

 $output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);


$mysqli_query = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db); 
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE userid LIKE '%$search%'") or die ("Could not search");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($count == 0){
  $output = "There was no search results!";

}else{

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $userid = $row ['userid'];
    $carno = $row ['carno'];
    $cost = $row ['cost'];
    $area = $row ['area'];
    $receipt = $row ['receipt'];

    $output .='<div> '.$userid.' '.$carno.' '.$cost.''.$area.' '.receipt.'</div>';

  }

}
}

?>
```

Preview:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRlk.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158990/discussion-on-question-by-wen-qing-how-to-search-and-display-items-through-php-h).

Comment: Hi friend, is your question solved?

Comment: Nope, i think i will use another method to do it... i'll let you know if it works :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me explain the following query:

`$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE userid LIKE '%$search%'") or die ("Could not search");`

You are searching `userid LIKE '%search%'`. Currently you are searching exactly '%search%' as text, while `$search` should contain `$_POST` data like 'Ronnie Oosting'. But i understand you want to have a variable which contains information you want to search on. This means you need to 'split' text and php. So a working query should be something like:

`$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE userid LIKE %'" . $search . "'%") or die ("Could not search");`

*note: I didnt test this, so let me know if you get results, or not.*

`$search` is a variable now, so you need to have `$search` set with data which can be hard coded, or in your case filled with `$_POST` data. Something like (which is not save): `$search = $_POST['something'];`

**In your case this should work:**

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);


$mysqli_query = new mysqli('spf', 'dbuser', 'dbpw', 'db'); 
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE userid = '" . $search . "'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

**Another note:**

You are using `$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);`. Which should be `$mysqli = new mysqli('spf', 'dbuser', 'dbpw', 'db');`